# Select the name and value of a colmun using 2 different inner joined columns' values

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I'm not sure if MySQL is capable of doing something like this. I'm no MySQL master by any means but to me this seems to be like it might be an example of a Pivot Table?

I've looked at other Pivot Table example and I find them confusing at best and I'm still not quite sure if it's relevant in my case.

### Here's an example of the data and tables in question:

#### Foo Table:

```
RowID | col_one | col_two | col_three
------|---------|---------|-----------
1     | 2       | 34      | 64
2     | 6       | 53      | 23
3     | 8       | 22      | 45
```

#### Foo_Meta Table:

```
RowID | FooID | MetaName | MetaValue
------|-------|----------|-----------
1     | 1     | This     | 302
2     | 1     | That     | 466
3     | 1     | Other    | 132
4     | 2     | This     | 222
5     | 2     | That     | 87
6     | 2     | Other    | 400
7     | 3     | This     | 732
8     | 3     | That     | 55
9     | 3     | Other    | 690
```

### Here's an example of the select I'm using but isn't quite what I'm looking for:

#### Select:

```
SELECT
    t.col_one,
    t.col_two,
    t.col_three,
    m.MetaName,
    m.MetaValue
FROM
    foo t
INNER JOIN
    foo_meta m ON t.RowID = m.FooID
```

### Here's an example of the table I'm trying to Select:

#### Select:

```
RowID | col_one | col_two | col_three | This | That | Other
------|---------|---------|---------------------------------
1     | 2       | 34      | 64        | 302  | 466  | 132
2     | 6       | 53      | 23        | 222  | 87   | 400
3     | 8       | 22      | 45        | 732  | 55   | 690
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are pivoting foo_meta fields - at least some versions of Oracle do that, I'm quite certain MySQL doesn't.

Generally, to "fake" a pivot in MySQL, you do multiple joins. Something like:

```
SELECT
    t.col_one,
    t.col_two,
    t.col_three,
    mthis.this,
    mthat.that,
    mother.other
FROM
    foo t
INNER JOIN
    (select fooid, MetaValue as This from foo_meta where MetaName = 'This') mthis ON t.RowID = mthis.FooID
INNER JOIN
    (select fooid, MetaValue as That from foo_meta where MetaName = 'That') mthat ON t.RowID = mthat.FooID
INNER JOIN
    (select fooid, MetaValue as Other from foo_meta where MetaName = 'Other') mother ON t.RowID = mother.FooID
```

You might have to use left outers depending on how your data is populated.